# Adaptive List View Help (Windows Universal App)

Tags: windows, xaml, win-universal-app

Below is my xaml code which defines `ListView`. The output is series of products. But the problem is the product aligns one after another.

[image: Image of universal output]

I Want an output align vertically one after another.

```
<ListView x:Name="list" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myCell">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >
                <Grid Margin="0" x:Name="tryadpative"   >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image x:Name="prodimg" Width="auto" Source="{Binding prodimg}" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="productcode"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding productcode}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Gray"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="productname" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Gray" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding productname}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="productmindec"  TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding productmindec}" Width="auto" FontSize="14"  Grid.Row="2" Foreground="Gray"/>

                    <!--<Image x:Name="prodimg" Width="auto" Source="{Binding prodimg}" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="productcode"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding productcode}"  Width="auto" FontSize="12"  Foreground="Gray"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="productname" FontSize="14"  Foreground="Gray"   Text="{Binding productname}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="productmindec"  TextWrapping="Wrap"   Text="{Binding productmindec}" Width="auto" FontSize="14"   Foreground="Gray"/>-->                                                                                 

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <!--<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>-->

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="myCell"/>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ItemsStackPanel can be used only as the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl that displays more than one item at a time. It can't be used with an ItemsControl that displays only one item at a time, such as a ComboBox or FlipView. ItemsStackPanel is the default ItemsPanel for ListView.
>
> By default, the ItemsStackPanel stacks items vertically from top to bottom. You can set the Orientation property to Horizontal to stack items from left to right.

For more info, see [ItemsStackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel).

We should be able to set the `Horizontal` to the `Orientation` of the `ItemsStackPanel`.

For example:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        </ItemsStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

By the way, if you want scroll the ListView in horizontal, you should be able to set the `Visible` to `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `Enabled` to the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode` in `ListView`.

For example:

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"  
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
</ListView>
```